# videojs buffer not playing when using php file

Tags: video.js, video-player

I have this player:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
<video id="milokan" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="480" autoplay data-setup="{}">
  <source src="play.php?file=<?php echo $code; ?>" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

AND play.php plays header("Content-Type: video/mp4");

This way there is no buffer, the player works but just when the whole file is done downloading.

How can I make it work and keep hiding the file I'm playing ?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you send the following headers in your response when serving up the video file:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 22474866 // (example)
Content-Range: bytes 539490-23014355/23014356 // (example)
Content-Type: video/mp4 // (example)
```

And make sure that you can serve files starting at a certain byte offset if the client requests that. This is required for seeking to work in HTML5 video/audio.

Comment: I think you only need rep to upvote an answer. Since you asked the question, you are able to accept it.